# How to cut a String into 1 megabyte subString with Java?

Tags: java

I have come up with the following:

```
public static void cutString(String s) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;
    while (index < s.length()) {
        strings.add(s.substring(index, Math.min(index + 1048576, s.length())));
        index += 1048576;
    }
}
```

But my problem is, that using UTF-8 some character doesn't exactly take 1 byte, so using 1048576 to tell where to cut the String is not working. I was thinking about maybe using Iterator, but that doesn't seem efficient. What'd be the most efficient solution for this? The String can be smaller than 1 Mb to avoid character slicing, just not bigger than that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick, unsafe hack**

You can use `s.getBytes("UTF-8")` to get an array with the actual bytes used by each UTF-8 character. Like this:

```
System.out.println("¡Adiós!".getBytes("UTF-8").length);
// Prints: 9
```

Once you have that, it's just a matter of splitting the byte array in chunks of length 1048576, and then turn the chunks back into UTF-8 strings with `new String(chunk, "UTF-8")`.

However, by doing it like that **you can break multi-byte characters at the beginning or end of the chunks**. Say the 1048576th character is a 3-byte Unicode character: the first byte would go into the first chunk and the other two bytes would get put into the second chunk, thus breaking the encoding.

#### Proper approach

If you can relax the "1 MB" requirement, you can take a safer approach: split the string in chunks of 1048576 characters (not bytes), and then test each chunk's real length with `getBytes`, removing chars from the end as needed until the real size is equal or less than 1 MB.

Here's an implementation that won't break characters, at the expense of having some lines smaller than the given size:

```
public static List<String> cutString(String original, int chunkSize, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    final int end = original.length();
    int from = 0, to = 0;
    do {
        to = (to + chunkSize > end) ? end : to + chunkSize; // next chunk, watch out for small strings
        String chunk = original.substring(from, to); // get chunk
        while (chunk.getBytes(encoding).length > chunkSize) { // adjust chunk to proper byte size if necessary
            chunk = original.substring(from, --to);
        }
        strings.add(chunk); // add chunk to collection
        from = to; // next chunk
    } while (to < end);
    return strings;
}
```

I tested it with `chunkSize = 24` so you could see the effect. It should work as well with any other size:

```
    String test = "En la fase de maquetación de un documento o una página web o para probar un tipo de letra es necesario visualizar el aspecto del diseño. ٩(-̮̮̃-̃)۶ ٩(●̮̮̃•̃)۶ ٩(͡๏̯͡๏)۶ ٩(-̮̮̃•̃).";

    for (String chunk : cutString(test, 24, "UTF-8")) {
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Chunk [%s] - Chars: %d - Bytes: %d",
                chunk, chunk.length(), chunk.getBytes("UTF-8").length));
    }
    /*
    Prints:
        Chunk [En la fase de maquetaci] - Chars: 23 - Bytes: 23
        Chunk [ón de un documento o un] - Chars: 23 - Bytes: 24
        Chunk [a página web o para pro] - Chars: 23 - Bytes: 24
        Chunk [bar un tipo de letra es ] - Chars: 24 - Bytes: 24
        Chunk [necesario visualizar el ] - Chars: 24 - Bytes: 24
        Chunk [aspecto del diseño. ٩(] - Chars: 22 - Bytes: 24
        Chunk [-̮̮̃-̃)۶ ٩(●̮̮] - Chars: 14 - Bytes: 24
        Chunk [̃•̃)۶ ٩(͡๏̯͡] - Chars: 12 - Bytes: 23
        Chunk [๏)۶ ٩(-̮̮̃•̃).] - Chars: 14 - Bytes: 24
     */
```

Another test with a 3 MB string like the one you mention in your comments:

```
    String string = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    StringBuilder bigAssString = new StringBuilder(1024*1024*3);
    for (int i = 0; i < ((1024*1024*3)/16); i++) {
        bigAssString.append(string);
    }
    System.out.println("bigAssString.length = " + bigAssString.toString().length());
    bigAssString.replace((1024*1024*3)/4, ((1024*1024*3)/4)+1, "á");

    for (String chunk : cutString(bigAssString.toString(), 1024*1024, "UTF-8")) {
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Chunk [...] - Chars: %d - Bytes: %d",
                chunk.length(), chunk.getBytes("UTF-8").length));
    }
    /*
    Prints:
        bigAssString.length = 3145728
        Chunk [...] - Chars: 1048575 - Bytes: 1048576
        Chunk [...] - Chars: 1048576 - Bytes: 1048576
        Chunk [...] - Chars: 1048576 - Bytes: 1048576
        Chunk [...] - Chars: 1 - Bytes: 1
     */
```

Comment: so basically I should run the method on the s.getBytes array, insted of on the String itself?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Correct. I'm in the middle of an edit to address this point. But that's gonna be a problem every time you want to split a UTF-8 string in chunks of a specific size. If the last char in the string is a 3-byte char, the only solution is to have the chunk be 1 byte smaller or 2 bytes bigger than required.

Comment: @dmbdnr Yes, kind of. I updated my answer so you can get an idea.

Comment: @walen thank you! yes, the size can be less than 1 Mb, just not bigger than that!

Comment: @dmbdnr Ok, give me a couple minutes and I'll update my answer with a "not bigger than 1 MB" example.

Comment: @dmbdnr There you go.

Comment: @walen it seems working with small chunkSize, but in my case I set the chunkSize to 1048576, and for a 1024*1024*3 digit long String it keeps running, and doesn't stop. The 1/4 of the String is a 3 byte size character 'á'. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The problem is in the do-while part, in the inner while. It keeps cutting back the substring with 1-3 bytes, and that part takes forever. Any solution for that?

Comment: @dmbdnr Tested it with a string like the one you said (I'll edit it in), and it works fine... as long as I remove `chunk` from the `println` statement and print only length and byte length, since printing multiple 1 MB strings to a terminal is not good for your health :P Surely you want to put these strings into a file of some type, don't you? Try that and see if it works.

Comment: @dmbdnr The character you pasted is a 2-byte one, by the way. Mind to tell me the exact Unicode code?

Comment: yeah right, 'á' is 2 byte. It works with your solution. but for example if I just create a 1024*1024*3 digit long string only containing 'á' character, and then I give chucnkSize 1024*1024, then it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @dmbdnr You mean the _whole_ 3 MB string being `"áá.....áá"`? That's a _very_ edge case. But the solution still works! It's only that, since "á" is 2 bytes long, our 1048576-character initial chunks have an actual byte length of 2097152 bytes... so the inner `while` has to remove 524288 "á" characters _one by one_ to get to the desired size. But the loop does end (eventually) and returns the correct chunks. You can implement the inner loop using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to avoid this, though the current implementation should be fine for most cases.

Comment: @walen it's not rare in my native language unfortunately :D would be so much easier with english only. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ByteArrayOutputStream with an OutputStreamWriter

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Writer w = OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-8");
    //write everything to the writer
    w.write(myString);
    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
    //now you have the actual size of the string, you can parcel by Mb. Be aware that problems may occur however if you have a multi-byte character separated into two locations
```