# Split Elasticsearch json request into chunks of 10MB size each

Tags: java, string, elasticsearch, size

I'm working on integrating Elasticsearch into an application and it looks like there's a constraint on the size of the request I send. It cannot be more than 10MB in size. Building a JSON request body for over 300 java objects is exceeding the provided limit. I think I can handle this in 2 cases:

Case 1: Keep checking the size of the request body as I'm building it and as soon as it reaches the limit, send the request.(I think this makes more sense)

Case 2: Build the entire JSON request, split it into chunks of 10MB each and send the requests.

Can someone help me in slicing this request into chunks of 10MB each?
Also, keep in mind that there's a possibility that a partial request can creep into the chunk.

I  have already looked at this SO post:
[How to cut a String into 1 megabyte subString with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499976/how-to-cut-a-string-into-1-megabyte-substring-with-java)

Just want to know if this is still the best approach to split a string into fixed chunk size or is there a better approach.

Thanks.

**[UPDATE 02/14 4:45pm]**
So I have come up with this code. This seemed to have at least not cause "Request size exceeded 10485760 bytes" error to pop. I see that the data is now indexed successfully. Any feedback on this code is really appreciated.

```
        // Convert the entityList to JSON
        long remainingChunkSize = 10000000; // 10MB size limit (not exact but this is ok)
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        List<String> reqChunkList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        boolean addChunkToList = false;


        for (EntityData entity : entityDataList) {
                indexName = (entity.getSearchable().get("search_entity")).toLowerCase();
                String chunk = String.format("{ \"index\" : { \"_index\" : \"%s\", \"_type\" : \"%s\", \"_id\" : \"%s\" } }\n%s\n",
                        indexName, "_doc", "mojo", gson.toJson(entity.getSearchable()));
                byte[] b = chunk.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // get the bytes
                long byteLength = b.length;

                if (byteLength < remainingChunkSize) {
                    sb.append(chunk);
                    remainingChunkSize -= byteLength;
                    addChunkToList = true;
                } else {
                    remainingChunkSize = 10000000;
                    reqChunkList.add(sb.toString());
                    sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
                    sb.append(chunk);
                    addChunkToList = true;
                    remainingChunkSize -= byteLength;
                }

        }

        if (addChunkToList) { // The last chunk 
            reqChunkList.add(sb.toString());
        }
```

Comment: I wonder if a third option could be doing a "gzip" to handle the JSON file

Comment: Still it will not guarantee that every request will be within the limit always. What if in the future if the list of data objects grow to 10000 or may be even bigger which I use to build JSON request with.

Comment: Then leaving that option, I would go for streaming the elasticsearch data, you may find examples using Kafta. Just saying